# What is a single word describing a person who opposes another, yet is of equal status to them?

Tags: single-word-requests

Can anyone give me a single word describing a person that is equal to somebody in status but an opponent to them at the same time?

Comment: Tough call. I think both @kriegar and @Purplegoldfish had good responses. I feel like maybe `rival` implies opposition whereas `counterpart` only implies complete equality. I.e., a counterpart might be completely amicable or on your side.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Rival" seems like a fitting choice.

Answer (score 9):

I agree *rival* is good - better than *counterpart*, which doesn't necessarily imply opposition.

I think *adversary* also fits the bill, and perhaps carries more overtones of actual equality. A *rival* may simply be an opponent who's strong enough to compete at all, but if you have an *adversary* you know you're in for a tough fight where the outcome isn't at all certain.

Comment: +1, but looking at the definitions of both words, I think adversary actually carries less intonation of equality.

Comment: In which case you'd be happy if I said you were my adversary in this arena :-)

Comment: Adding some meat to the bones, Google shows 131,000 hits for "*more powerful adversary*", as against 108,000 for "*more powerful rival*", so it obviously has stronger associations with power. Particularly considering the bare word *rival* outhits *adversary* by an order of magnitude.

Comment: I don't think using Google hits helps your argument. On the contrary, I think the fact that there are more hits with the modifier weakens your position. If anything it shows that rival means an equal or greater opponent, where as adversary needs a modifier to implicate scale of the opponent. That being said, Google hits for a phrase is probably a poor indication of anything. Looking at the definitions again, rival seems to be the better choice.

Answer (score 4):

Moriarty was Sherlock Holmes' ***arch-enemy***.

Superman's ***nemesis*** was Lex Luthor.

Answer (score 2):

"Your opposite number" is sometimes used.

Comment: that sounds rather poetic .)

Comment: It doesn't to me, but it also doesn't necessarily connote opposition. Its primary meaning to me is "the person in another organisation whose position or function most closely corresponds to yours, and who therefore you might well be dealing with, or deal with in the future.

Answer (score 1):

[*Archrival*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archrival) is a particularly apt description for this sort of person. [*Competitor*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/competitor?show=0&t=1301454274) comes a close second in my book.

Answer (score 0):

*Counterpart* might be one, depends on the usage though.

Answer (score 0):

"Antithesis".
In the Neil Gaiman series Sandman, the term Corinthian is used, referring to an Roman poem wherein the Corinthians were shown to be the Dark Mirrors of the protagonists.

Answer (score 0):

I think "opponent" is close to what you might be looking for.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You may be unfamiliar with StackExchange; this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and answers are expected to provide detailed explanations, including citations or links to appropriate references. For guidance, I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score -1):

"Bizarro" can also be used, though it assumes a certain amount of comic-savvy.

Comment: Sorry, but Bizarro has a whole other set of connotations that make it a bad answer to this question.

Answer (score -1):

Contrarian a person who takes up a contrary position, especially a position that is opposed to that of the majority